# Best ORM that can work with Service Broker and transactions

Tags: .net, orm, service-broker

Greetings

Is there a ORM (MS-Sql specific) that can work with transactions and is Service Broker friendly. What I’m searching for is the ability to work with the ORM tables, inside a transaction, and be able to do service broker calls inside the transaction (either by using an ORM object/method or by directly executing a command.ExecuteNonQuery). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Almost any ORM supports this - there is nothing special, you need just transactions support and direct SQL command execution. So I'd focus on different criteria for choosing ORM ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest NHibernate.